# How to install python-igraph?

Tags: 12.04, package-management, ppa

I am following [these](http://igraph.wikidot.com/installing-python-igraph-on-linux#toc0) instructions to install python-igraph. Adding PPA words and update works. But the install complains of the following:

> Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "python-igraph"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, there is no `python-igraph` package for 12.04. Because of that, you get the error when you try to install it in 12.04. You can check the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~igraph/+archive/ppa) for yourself.

It does have a package for 11.10 though. If you are desperate, you can [download](https://launchpad.net/~igraph/+archive/ppa/+packages) the deb package meant for 11.10 and install it manually. Hopefully, you can install it without much dependency problem.

Comment: Or you can have someone try and retrofit the package for 12.04, it should still work

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better you to build it from source like in the Debian Lenny section, present in igraph wiki.

Follow this link: http://igraph.wikidot.com/installing-python-igraph-on-linux#toc2